# Looping through different multiple videos using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to loop videos from external source like Vimeo , one after the other.  I have successfully captured the event when the video ends playing for Vimeo.

However, how could i loop through `multiple videos` one after the another.

Below is my code, which captures finish event of a single video. any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="froogaloop.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
            player = $f(iframe),
            status = $('.status');

        // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
        player.addEvent('ready', function() {
            status.text('ready');

            player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
            player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
            player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
        });

        // Call the API when a button is pressed
        $('button').bind('click', function() {
            player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
        });

        function onPause(id) {
            status.text('paused');
        }

        function onFinish(id) {
            status.text('finished');
        }

        function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
            status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
        }

    }); 
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <article>

            <iframe id="player1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/470742?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <p>Video status: <span class="status">...</span></p>
            <p><button>Play</button> <button>Pause</button></p>

        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to repeat same video or want to play some other video

Comment: I want to play other videos, sorry for the confusion in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your onFinish function with this one

```
function onFinish(id) {
    status.text('finished');
    $("#player1").attr("src","new video url here")
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/HfwWY/light/)

Comment: HI Jeetendra, i don't want to play the same video again, i want to load a new video, like a playlist, Sorry for the confusion in my question

Comment: i have modified my answer please try that